# Copy and Paste across Folders in a loop with VBA

Tags: excel, copy-paste, worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to write a loop that copies and pastes a range of data from one workbook to another. I get stuck with the error `'Select Sheet method not proper'` or whatever the error message is. This is what I have so far:

```
folderpath="insert folder path here"
Filename = Dir(folderPath)
Do While Filename <> ""

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename)

wb.Worksheets("Outcomes & Factors Rankings").Select
Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 6)).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OutcomeFactorRankings").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select.Paste

wb.Close

Loop
```

Comment: Don't select the worksheet just to copy from it. Instead of four lines, just: `wb.Worksheets("Outcomes & Factors Rankings").Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 6)).Copy Destination:= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OutcomeFactorRankings").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)`

Comment: now error is: "unable to get the select worksheet property." Never experienced this before.

Comment: Apologies. I left an errant SELECT in there: `wb.Worksheets("Outcomes & Factors Rankings").Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 6)).Copy Destination:= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OutcomeFactorRankings").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)`

Comment: now it is Application defined or Object defined error. Thank you so much by the way

Comment: That makes sense. So that `Range("A3").End(xlDown)...` bit needs to be qualified to which workbook/worksheet that range should exist in. So the statement grows: `wb.Worksheets("Outcomes & Factors Rankings").Range("A3", wb.Worksheets("Outcomes & Factors Rankings").Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 6)).Copy Destination:= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OutcomeFactorRankings").Range("A1")‌​.End(xlDown).Offset(‌​1, 0)`  That's pretty long, but it should do the trick. You can also split this into two lines of code like the 1 answer below (which suffers from the same problem as my previous comment).

Comment: any idea how I would get to the next file in the folder now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to indent your code, you don't need all those selects in your code, simplify, something like that should solve your problem:

```
folderPath = "insert folder path here"
    Filename = Dir(folderPath)

    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename)
        wb.Worksheets("Outcomes & Factors Rankings").Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 6)).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OutcomeFactorRankings").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Paste
        wb.Close
    Loop
```

Comment: Will indent next time. But I get an error, Application defined or Object defined error. On the wb.WorkSheets()....Copy line